# using python to find length of list by recurssion

Tags: python, recursion

I have a function here and I want it to count the length of list like 1,2,3,4,5 =5
but the function only counts numbers 1234=4 
how can i fix this

```
def mylen(alist):
        if alist:
               return 1 + mylen(alist[1:])
        return 0        

def main():
       alist=input("Enter a list of number :")
       print(mylen(alist))
main()
```

fyi i cannot use len

Comment: huh?  len("1234") is 4 .... whats the question?

Comment: i want it to count length of list

Comment: example   input=[1,2,3,4,5] output=5 and not 9 like how i am getting currently

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want mylen('1234') to be = 1.  Take your input and split up the numbers by the comma separator.

```
def mylen(alist):
        if alist:
               return 1 + mylen(alist[1:])
        return 0        

def main():
       alist=input("Enter a number :")
       print(mylen(alist.split(','))
main()
```

There is no need for the computer to do so much processing for something that is built into the language.  This will work just fine:

```
alist=input("Enter a number :")
print(len(alist.split(','))
```

Comment: i am trying to find the length using recurssion

Comment: the length of what? ( the string value?  or the list of numbers (integers)?)

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding i meant list of numbers

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3:

```
   alist=input("Enter a list of number :")
```

`alist` will now be a string. If you enter "1,2,3,4,5", `a list` will be the string `"1,2,3,4,5"`, not a list of numbers `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

A string is a *sequence type*, just like a list, so your code works with the string as well, and counts the number of elements (characters) in it.

You can use `split` to convert the input in a list:

```
   userinput = input("Enter a list of number :")
   alist = userinput.split(",")
```

(Note that this is still a list of strings, not numbers, but this doesn't matter for this exercise.)